# RecursionError in Ray Tracing Code: "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python

I'm working on a ray tracing project in Python, and I'm encountering a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in my code. The error occurs within the get_raycolor function, which is responsible for handling ray intersections with scene primitives.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def get_raycolor(ray):
    distances = []
    hit_orientation = []
    for s in Sc['scene_primitives']:
        if isinstance(s,list):
            if s[0] == 'sphere':
                a = sphere_intersect(s,ray['origin'],ray['dir'])
            elif s[0] == 'plane':
                a = plane_intersect(s,ray['origin'],ray['dir'])
            else:
                a = cuboid_intersect(s,ray['origin'],ray['dir'])
        else:
            a = s.intersect(ray['origin'], ray['dir'])
        distances.append(a[0])
        hit_orientation.append(a[1])
    nearest = np.minimum.reduce(distances)
    color = vec3(0., 0., 0.)
    for (coll, dis , orient) in zip(Sc['scene_primitives'], distances, hit_orientation):
        hit_check = (nearest != FARAWAY) & (dis == nearest)
        if np.any(hit_check):
            if isinstance(coll,list):
                if coll[0] == 'sphere':
                    color += coll[4].get_color({'origin':ray['origin'].extract(hit_check),'dir':ray['dir'].extract(hit_check),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':ray['n'].extract(hit_check),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'],'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']}, {'distance':extract(hit_check,dis),'orientation':extract(hit_check,orient),'collider':coll,'u':None,'v':None,'point':None}).place(hit_check)
                elif coll[0] == 'cuboid':
                    color += coll[5].get_color({'origin':ray['origin'].extract(hit_check),'dir':ray['dir'].extract(hit_check),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':ray['n'].extract(hit_check),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'],'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']}, {'distance':extract(hit_check,dis),'orientation':extract(hit_check,orient),'collider':coll,'u':None,'v':None,'point':None}).place(hit_check)
                else:
                    color += coll[6].get_color({'origin':ray['origin'].extract(hit_check),'dir':ray['dir'].extract(hit_check),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':ray['n'].extract(hit_check),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'],'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']}, {'distance':extract(hit_check,dis),'orientation':extract(hit_check,orient),'collider':coll,'u':None,'v':None,'point':None}).place(hit_check)
            else:
                color += coll.material.get_color({'origin':ray['origin'].extract(hit_check),'dir':ray['dir'].extract(hit_check),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':ray['n'].extract(hit_check),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'],'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']}, {'distance':extract(hit_check,dis),'orientation':extract(hit_check,orient),'collider':coll,'u':None,'v':None,'point':None}).place(hit_check)
    return color
class Refractive:
    def __init__(self, n, **kwargs):
        self.n = n
    def get_color(self, ray, hit):
        hit['point'] = (ray['origin'] + ray['dir'] * hit['distance'])
        if isinstance(hit['collider'],list):
            if hit['collider'][0] == 'sphere':
                N = (hit['point'] - hit['collider'][3]) * (1. / hit['collider'][5])*hit['orientation']
                max_depth = hit['collider'][2]
            elif hit['collider'][0] == 'cuboid':
                N = cuboid_get_Normal(hit['collider'],hit)
                max_depth = hit['collider'][8]
            else:
                N = hit['collider'][4]
                max_depth = hit['collider'][3]
        else:
            N = hit['collider'].get_Normal(hit)*hit['orientation']
            max_depth = hit['collider'].max_ray_depth
        color = vec3(0.,0.,0.)
        V = ray['dir']*-1.
        nudged = hit['point'] + N * .000001
        if ray['depth'] <max_depth:
            n1 = ray['n']
            n2 = vec3(np.where(hit['orientation']== UPWARDS, self.n.x, Sc['n'].x),np.where(hit['orientation']== UPWARDS, self.n.y, Sc['n'].y),np.where(hit['orientation']== UPWARDS, self.n.z, Sc['n'].z))
            n1_div_n2 =  vec3(np.real(n1.x), np.real(n1.y), np.real(n1.z))/vec3(np.real(n2.x), np.real(n2.y), np.real(n2.z))
            cosdeltai = V.dot(N)
            sin2deltat = (n1_div_n2)**2 * (1.-cosdeltai**2)
            vv = 1. - (n1/n2)**2 * (1.-cosdeltai**2)
            cosdeltat = vec3(np.sqrt(vv.x) , np.sqrt(vv.y) ,np.sqrt(vv.z))
            r_per = (n1*cosdeltai - n2*cosdeltat)/(n1*cosdeltai + n2*cosdeltat)
            r_par = -1.*(n1*cosdeltat - n2*cosdeltai)/(n1*cosdeltat + n2*cosdeltai) 
            F = (np.abs(r_per)**2 + np.abs(r_par)**2)/2.
            reflected_ray_dir = (ray['dir'] - N * 2. * ray['dir'].dot(N)).normalize()
            color += (get_raycolor({'origin':nudged, 'dir':reflected_ray_dir, 'depth':ray['depth'] + 1, 'n':ray['n'], 'reflections':ray['reflections'] + 1, 'transmissions':ray['transmissions'], 'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']}))*F
            n1_div_n2_aver = (n1_div_n2.x + n1_div_n2.y +  n1_div_n2.z)/3
            sin2deltat = (n1_div_n2_aver)**2 * (1.-cosdeltai**2)
            non_TiR = (sin2deltat <= 1.)
            if np.any(non_TiR):
                color += (get_raycolor( {'origin':(hit['point'] - N * .000001).extract(non_TiR),'dir':(ray['dir']*(n1_div_n2_aver) + N*(n1_div_n2_aver * cosdeltai - np.sqrt(1-np.clip(sin2deltat,0,1)))).normalize().extract(non_TiR),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':n2.extract(non_TiR),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'] + 1,'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']})  )*(1. - F).extract(non_TiR).place(non_TiR)
            vv = -2.*vec3(np.imag(ray['n'].x), np.imag(ray['n'].y), np.imag(ray['n'].z))*2.*np.pi/vec3(630,550,475) * 1e9* hit['distance']
            color = color *vec3(np.exp(vv.x) , np.exp(vv.y) ,np.exp(vv.z))
        return color
```

The error seems to be triggered by the following line:

```
color += (get_raycolor( {'origin':(hit['point'] - N * .000001).extract(non_TiR),'dir':(ray['dir']*(n1_div_n2_aver) + N*(n1_div_n2_aver * cosdeltai - np.sqrt(1-np.clip(sin2deltat,0,1)))).normalize().extract(non_TiR),'depth':ray['depth'],'n':n2.extract(non_TiR),'reflections':ray['reflections'],'transmissions':ray['transmissions'] + 1,'diffuse_reflections':ray['diffuse_reflections']})  )*(1. - F).extract(non_TiR).place(non_TiR)
```

I have already tried adding debugging prints to trace the flow of execution, and it seems that the loop inside get_raycolor is being executed excessively, printing the details of a specific collider over a thousand times. Here's an example of the output:

coll:

```
['cuboid', True, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E690>, 0.9, 1.0, <__main__.Refractive object at 0x000001FCF0BD60C0>, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E780>, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E7B0>, 5, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E6C0>, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E6F0>, <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E720>, array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]]), array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]]), 0.4]
```

ray:

```
{'origin': <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3E9F0>, 'dir': <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0C3EAB0>, 'depth': 0, 'n': <__main__.vec3 object at 0x000001FCF0BD5E20>, 'reflections': 0, 'transmissions': 0, 'diffuse_reflections': 0}
```

Could someone help me identify the root cause of the recursion error and provide guidance on how to fix it? Any suggestions for debugging or improving my code structure would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys i realized that i missed `*hit['orientation']` in this line

```
elif hit['collider'][0] == 'cuboid':
   N = cuboid_get_Normal(hit['collider'],hit)
```

Corrected:

```
elif hit['collider'][0] == 'cuboid':
   N = cuboid_get_Normal(hit['collider'],hit)*hit['orientation']
```